# SQL how to select pairs of rows where dates are consecutive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following simple table:

```
create table Table1(
ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[Date] datetime
)
```

And I need a select query that returns pairs of row grouped 2 by 2 with the condition that the Date values of the rows must be consecutive. Which returns something like this:

```
1   2014-08-10 09:29:53.160 2   2014-08-11 09:29:53.160
2   2014-08-11 09:29:53.160 3   2014-08-12 09:29:53.160
3   2014-08-12 09:29:53.160 4   2014-08-13 09:29:53.160
4   2014-08-13 09:29:53.160 5   2014-08-14 09:29:53.160
```

I did this query:

```
select * from Table1 t1
inner join Table1 t2 on t1.ID < t2.ID
where t2.Date = DATEADD(DD,1,t1.Date)
```

But the problem is that the query should return pairs of rows even if the difference between the 2 dates is more than one, it could be 2, 3, 10, x...
Also I was told that the `t1.ID < t2.ID` verification is not ok, I should threat cases like this:

```
2   2014-08-09 09:29:53.160
1   2014-08-10 09:29:53.160
```

Also the query should be fast when working with a big number of inserted rows.

What I mean is that if I have the following input:

```
1   2014-08-09 09:29:53.160 
2   2014-08-11 09:29:53.160 
3   2014-08-12 09:29:53.160 
4   2014-08-14 09:29:53.160 
5   2014-08-18 09:29:53.160
```

then the output should be:

```
1 2014-08-09 09:29:53.160 2 2014-08-11 09:29:53.160 
2 2014-08-11 09:29:53.160 3 2014-08-12 09:29:53.160 
3 2014-08-12 09:29:53.160 4 2014-08-14 09:29:53.160
4 2014-08-14 09:29:53.160 5 2014-08-18 09:29:53.160
```

The correct answer was given to me by someone but I see that he deleted the answer. It is:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.[Date],
  x.id,
  x.[Date]
FROM
  Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT top 1 percent 
    [Date],
    ID
  FROM 
    Table1
  WHERE 
    t1.[Date] < [Date]
  ORDER BY [Date]
) x
```

Thanks to everyone that tried to help me.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: OK. Also, what do you mean by "the query should return pairs of rows even if the difference between the 2 dates is more than one"? That isn't consecutive. Can you please provide some sample input and expected output to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id
,Current_Row.EFF_DATE
,case when NextRow.EFF_DATE is null then '20991231' else NextRow.EFF_DATE end
from TABLE1 as Current_Row
left join TABLE1 as NextRow
on NextRow.iD = Current_Row.iD + 1
```

If don't need to have an interval for last date you can replace     ,case when NextRow.EFF_DATE is null then '20991231' else NextRow.EFF_DATE end with NextRow.EFF_DATE and left join with inner join

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Date, t3.ID AS ID1, t3.Date AS Date1 
FROM Table1 AS t1
    OUTER APPLY 
        (SELECT TOP 1 t2.ID, t2.Date 
            FROM Table1 AS t2
            WHERE t2.Date <= t1.Date AND t2.ID < t1.ID
            ORDER BY t2.Date DESC, t2.ID DESC) AS t3
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/937e2/9)